# Accessing Key from Exploded String

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I am having difficulty pulling a key from an exploded string. I can get the exploded string to print all of the values and keys, but how to I store the key as a variable? Here is my example:

```
<?php
$str = 'one,two,three,four';
print_r(explode(',', $str));
?>
```

The above code will print out:

```
Array
(
[0] => one
[1] => two
[2] => three
)
```

Anyone know how to access these keys? What would I do if I only wanted to echo out the [1] key? Any help would be great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

store the exploded value in an array...

```
$str = 'one,two,three,four';
$temparray=explode(',', $str);

echo $temparray[1];  // two
echo $temparray[0];  // one....
```

Comment: Hmmmm. I just tried that prior to posting. I think i may have had an extra set of parentheses... Well your code works perfectly. THANK YOU

Comment: Says I can't accept your answer for 9 minutes. Will accept it ASAP. Thanks!